# Why is event parameter forgotten after recursion?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following code:

```
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8"> 

<title>title...</title>

<link type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="dialog1" style="display: none">
<p>some text</p>
</div>

<input id="but1" type="button" value="clickme" />

</body>  

<script>

$("#but1").on ('click', {valu: 1}, f);

$("#dialog1").dialog({ autoOpen:false });

function f (event) {
    console.log(event.data.valu); // EXISTS
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "event.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(event.data.valu); // DOESN'T EXIST
            var promptDialog = $("#dialog1");
            var promptDialogButtons = {};
            promptDialogButtons['ok'] = function(){
                $("#dialog1").on('click', { valu: 0 }, f);
                $("#dialog1").click();
                $("#dialog1").dialog('close');
            };
            promptDialogButtons['cancel'] = function(){
                $("#dialog1").dialog('close');
            };
            promptDialog.dialog({ width:333, modal: true, title: "sometitle", buttons:promptDialogButtons});
            $("#dialog1").dialog('open');
        }
    });
}

</script>


</html>
```

When clicking on "clickme" and then "ok" the output will be:

```
1
1
0
TypeError: event.data is null
```

Why is `event.data.valu` forgotten in the `$.ajax()` after recursion? No redeclaration of parameter `event` in the `$.ajax()`. Please fill in the valid path to the JQuery libraries. Use any valid `event.xml` file.

Comment: Create a live demo that replicates problem

Comment: It's all very strange, I'm guessing the original event is lost when you overwrite the element that triggered it by calling `dialog` on the same element again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the jquery-ui dialogue does handle the click event of the ok button differently. your problem could be solved by calling the function f directly within the success function.

```
f({ data:{
       valu: 0
     }
});
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/klickagent/3L1zro7w/8/
for a working example

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I have a question: your change is fully equivalent with the existing code, except that `event` is passed correctly in your version? Because I figured out that also storing `event.data.valu` into local variable is also a solution. I have these `event` parameters on many places in the code and if I will make a change I would like to keep the sourcecode as intact as possible.